# Computing: $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+a)((\ln x)^2+\pi^2)}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, complex-integration

Assume $a>0$ and evaluate $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+a)((\ln x)^2+\pi^2)}.$$

My biggest issue when doing these problems is deciding which closed curve I should try, so if someone could point me in the right direction with at least that I would appreciate it!

Comment: Try integrating the function $\frac{1}{(z+a)(\ln z - i \pi)}$ around a keyhole contour, where the branch cut is along the positive real axis.

Comment: My biggest issue with problems is how to solve them, too.

Comment: @ProfessorVector that's life :(